# Blender 2.79 physics and simulation

Tags: physics

I want to create a simulation where there is a core and at these core objects are attracted to it gradually till they form the shape of the core e.g Sphere core like Chibaku Tensei. How can I achieve these, need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach, there are probably better ones

Turn off gravity[image]

Add the object you want to attract objects to and give it a force field

[image]

Set the strength of the field to a negative value. and the shape to "Surface"

Make it a passive rigid body

[image]

enable rigid body collision and set bounciness to 0 and friction to 1

[image]

Add the objects you want to move and give them a rigid body type of active

[image]

If you animate this the objects will move to the body and stick.  You'll need to tune the force strength to get the speed you want.

Comment: Thanks man. I hope I get what I want through these method.